# Webflux: CancelledServerWebExchangeException appears in metrics for seemingly no reason

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-boot-actuator

After upgrading to spring-boot 2.5, `CancelledServerWebExchangeException` started to appear in prometheus `http_server_requests_seconds` metrics quite frequently (up to 10% server responses end up with it, according to graphics). It appears in my own API metrics, as well as actuator endpoints metrics (health, info, prometheus).

Example:
`http_server_requests_seconds_count{exception="CancelledServerWebExchangeException",method="GET",outcome="UNKNOWN",status="200",uri="/actuator/health"} 137.0`
Kind of strange combination of outcome="UNKNOWN" & status="200"

The problem is: all these requests have successful responses.

Questions: what is this exception for and why may it occur so often?

How to reproduce: start application locally and put some load on it (I used 50 threads in jmeter accessing actuator endpoints)

Comment: hi Sergey, did you find a solution for this?

Comment: not yet, I'm not working with webflux services at the moment